# Facing difficulty in working $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{ax}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to evaluate this integral,$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{ax}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}\tag1$$

This is the approach I will take:

We can begin with a sub: $y=\sqrt{x}$, $dx=2\sqrt{x}dy$

$$-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{ay^2}{y^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{dy}{y^2}\tag2$$

Not sure, but we can try integration by parts: $u=\arctan\left(\frac{ay^2}{y^2-1}\right)$, $$du=\frac{2ay}{y^2-1}-\frac{2ay^3}{(y^2-1)^2}\times \frac{1}{\frac{a^2y^4}{(y^2-1)^2}+1}dy$$

$dv=\frac{1}{y^2\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy$, $$v=-\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}$$

$$2a\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-y^2)^{3/2}}{(y^2-1)+a^2y^4}+2a\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^2(1-y^2)^{1/2}}{(y^2-1)^2+a^2y^4}dy=2a\left(I+J\right)\tag3$$

Integral I: Making another sub: $y=\sin(u)$, $u=\arcsin(y)$, $dy=\cos(u) du$

It is too much to write everything down, finally got to:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{cos^4(u)}{a^2\sin^4(u)+\cos^4(u)}du$$

Using trig identities we can rewrite

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sec^2(u)\frac{du}{(1+\tan^2(u))(1+a^2\tan^4(u))}$$

Make another sub: $s=\tan(u)$, $du=\frac{1}{\sec^2(s)}ds$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{(1+s^2)(1+a^2s^4)}$$

Using partial fraction decomp:

$$I=\frac{\pi}{2(a^2+1)}-\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s^2-1}{a^2s^4+1}ds$$

Integral J: Making another sub: $y=\sin(v)$, $v=\arcsin(y)$, $dy=\cos(v) dv$

$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(v)\sin^2(v)}{(a^2+1)\sin^4(v)-2\sin^2(v)+1}$$

Using trig identities to rewrite

$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sec^2(v)\cdot \frac{\tan^2(v)}{(1+\tan^2(v))(a^2\tan^4(v)+1)}$$

Make another sub: $t=\tan(v)$, $dv=\frac{1}{\sec^2(v)}dt$

$$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{(1+t^2)(1+a^2t^4)}dt$$

Using partial fraction decomp:

$$J=\frac{1}{1+a^2}\color{red}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{a^2t^2+1}{a^2t^4+1}dt}-\frac{\pi}{2(1+a^2)}$$

The red integral it is definitely way out of my reach!

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{a^2t^2+1}{a^2t^4+1}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{t^4+a^{-2}}dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{a^2t^4+1}$$

The above approach seem to be not helping in evaluating the question.

After simplification I got to:

$$2a(I+J)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{ax}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x}}\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}
=\frac{1}{1+a^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{a^2+1}{a^2t^4+1}dt$$

If my work so far it is correct, then I am shruggle in solving this integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2t^4+1}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{(at^2-i)(at^2+i)}dt$$

Comment: There is no question, so you only need an evaluation of the red integral or what?

Comment: I need to evaluate the entire question if that is possible with you

Comment: @Bonjour Hint: Put $t=\frac{1}{x}$ in both of those integrals separately and use partial fractions with imaginary coefficients on each of them.

Comment: Well I am good at how to deal with imaginary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$*I don't think your last integral is correct. You have made a mistake somewhere which I could not find.*

Assume wolog $a\geq 0$ (because the case $a<0$ follows from the case $a>0$ by noticing that the arctangent is an odd function). Let the original integral be $F(a)$. Set $u=\frac{x}{1-x}$ to get:
$$F(a)= \int^\infty_0 \frac{\arctan(au)}{u^{3/2}}\,du$$
Integrate by parts to get:
$$F(a)= 2\int^\infty_0 \frac{a}{\sqrt[]{u} (1+a^2u^2)}\,du$$

Now set $t=a u$ to get:
$$F(a) = 2\sqrt[]{a} \int^\infty_0 \frac{dt}{\sqrt[]{t}(1+t^2)}$$This integral can be easily found using Residue Theorem or many other methods. For instance you can set $z=\sqrt[]{t}$ to get:
$$F(a) = 4 \sqrt[]{a} \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{1+z^4}\,dz = 2\sqrt[]{a} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{1}{1+z^4}\,dz = 2\sqrt[]{a} \ \ \Im \left[ \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{1}{z^2-i}\,dz \right]$$ 
Using the Residue Theorem by enclosing the pole at $e^{i\pi/4}$ we conclude that:
$$F(a) = 2\sqrt[]{a} \Im\left[ \pi i e^{-i\pi/4}\right]  = \sqrt[]{2a}\  \pi$$
That was for $a>0$. In general $$F(a) = \operatorname{sign} (a) \sqrt[]{2|a|}\ \pi$$

Comment: I have skipped details concerning the Resdidue Theorem, let me know if you need it. Because I had no mich time when I was writing this. Moreover, the main step was to reduce the integral to something well known, like $$\int^\infty_0 \frac{x^\mu} {1+x^2}dx$$ which is just a Mellin Transform. Many people have wrote about it in MathStackechange, I suggest you look them up.

Comment: ok, I will look into it, thank you